# How to pass objects to a javascript function from HTML href link?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function createListItem(text1) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    var text = text1;
    link.setAttribute("name", text);
    link.setAttribute("href", "javascript:updateLevel1(text)");
    //link.setAttribute("onclick", "updateLevel1()");
    var list_item = document.createElement("li");
    var list_text = document.createTextNode(text);
    list_item.appendChild(list_text);
    link.appendChild(list_item);
    return link;
}

function updateLevel1(text) {
    clearNavFrame2();
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("name", text);
    link.setAttribute("href", "javascript:updateLevel1(text)");
    link.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    document.getElementById("navigation_frame1").appendChild(link);
}
```

Here i want to pass the object text to the function updateLevel1 when i dynamically created an HTML link but unfortunately above code is not working. The function updateLevel1 is not able to figure out the object text. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: You may use jquery. It could ease your coding much. In this case you could take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: yea i thought about jquery but when i went through some code of jquery it looked hard to understand and i wanted to use only basic functionalities of jscript. but anyway thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to break your string and insert the value text has literally.

`link.setAttribute("href", "javascript:updateLevel1('" + text + "')");`

**Just be careful** - you may need to clean text if it contains any single quotes.

If this is a possibility you'll want to run something like `text = text.replace("'", "\\'");`

Comment: Yea the below worked

link.setAttribute("href", "javascript:updateLevel1('" + text+"')");
Thanks adam. You are great.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're doing something incorrectly.  First, instead of setting the "href" attribute, you can add a "click" handler to the element:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.onclick = function() { updateLevel1(text); };
```

There's really no reason to use "javascript:" URLs in a case like this.

Now, another problem you've got is that you create that `<a>` element but you don't append it to the document (in the code you posted).  I suppose that somewhere, you use the return value from the "createListItem()" function and append it then.  If not, well, nothing will really happen.

The reason that your "javascript:" value for "href" doesn't work is that you're setting up a situation wherein the browser will create a function from that string when the `<a>` is clicked. At that point, the local variable "text" from that function is long gone.  When you use an actual function reference bound to the "onclick" property of the `<a>`, however, your function will retain access to that variable in its closure.

Comment: the problem with using the onclick is that, if i dont mention the href attribute of element a then it will not display the element at all on the web page (i experienced it). and if i mention the href attribute along with the onclick then what should i put at those two places. So i used only the href attribute for calling jscript method. and regarding the append, yes i am appending it to the document in another function :)

Comment: My browser (Firefox) certainly displays the contents of `<a>` tags whether or not they have an "href" attribute. You can always use "#" for the href if you must have one.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an event handler:

```
function createListItem(text1) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    var text = text1;
    link.setAttribute("name", text);
    link.setAttribute("href", "#");

    link.onclick = function(){
    updateLevel1( text );
    return false;
    };

    var list_item = document.createElement("li");
    var list_text = document.createTextNode(text);
    list_item.appendChild(list_text);
    link.appendChild(list_item);
    return link;
}

function updateLevel1(text) {
    clearNavFrame2();
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("name", text);

        link.onclick = function(){
        updateLevel1( text );
        return false;
        };
    link.setAttribute("href", "#" );
    link.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    document.getElementById("navigation_frame1").appendChild(link);
}
```

Comment: This is also a good option. I did not know about this functionality  link.setAttribute("href", "#");
I will try this once. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `link.setAttribute("href", "javascript:updateLevel1(this);`

Then you read it inside your function by its reference. eg:

```
function updateLevel1(elm) {
    clearNavFrame2();
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("name", elm.name);  
    ...
}
```

Comment: i tried using the object this but it don't work. I read somewhere that it passes the object of window instead of the html element.

Comment: Pointy is right, you shouldn't do that. Use plein Javascript with `link.onclick = ...`or inline if necessary `<a href="javascript:" onclick="updateLevel1(this)>...</a>` but please not this string ugliness.